# StackOverflowError using joda-time new Period(long)

Tags: java, stack-overflow, jodatime

First, sorry this is so long. I probably don't need all the code, but wanted to be sure.

Second, my actual question is, am I doing something wrong, or is this a bug in the joda-time library?

I'm trying to use joda-time (1.6.1) to calculate, then format time durations.

I'm currently using `Period`, which may be the wrong choice. Please let me know if it is.
However, even if it is the wrong choice, I'm pretty sure this shouldn't happening.

I'm initialising a `Period` using milliseconds (by multiplying a duration in seconds by 1000). I'm using the `Period` so I can then format it and print it:

```
long durationLong = durationSec * 1000;
Period duration = new Period(durationLong);

PeriodFormatter daysHoursMinutes = new PeriodFormatterBuilder()
    .appendHours()
    .appendSeparator(":")
    .appendMinutes()
    .appendSeparator(":")
    .appendSeconds()
    .toFormatter();

String formattedString = daysHoursMinutes.print(callDuration.normalizedStandard());
```

I get the Exception below, and have looked through the source to confirm the loop.

```
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.util.Hashtable.get(Hashtable.java:274)
    at java.util.Properties.getProperty(Properties.java:177)
    at java.lang.System.getProperty(System.java:440)
    at java.lang.System.getProperty(System.java:412)
    at org.joda.time.DateTimeZone.getDefault(DateTimeZone.java:132)
    at org.joda.time.DateTimeZone.forID(DateTimeZone.java:190)
    at org.joda.time.DateTimeZone.getDefault(DateTimeZone.java:132)
    at org.joda.time.DateTimeZone.forID(DateTimeZone.java:190)

...snip (all the same)...

    at org.joda.time.DateTimeZone.getDefault(DateTimeZone.java:132)
    at org.joda.time.DateTimeZone.forID(DateTimeZone.java:190)
    at org.joda.time.DateTimeZone.getDefault(DateTimeZone.java:132)
    at org.joda.time.DateTimeZone.forID(Dat
```

Period(long):

```
public Period(long duration) {
    super(duration, null, null);
}
```

super(long, PeriodType, Chronology):

```
protected BasePeriod(long duration, PeriodType type, Chronology chrono) {
    super();
    type = checkPeriodType(type);
    chrono = DateTimeUtils.getChronology(chrono);
    iType = type;
    iValues = chrono.get(this, duration);
}
```

DateTimeUtils.getChronology(chrono):

```
public static final Chronology getChronology(Chronology chrono) {
    if (chrono == null) {
        return ISOChronology.getInstance();
    }
    return chrono;
}
```

ISOChronology.getInstance():

```
public static ISOChronology getInstance() {
    return getInstance(DateTimeZone.getDefault());
}
```

DateTimeZone.getDefault():

```
public static DateTimeZone getDefault() {
    DateTimeZone zone = cDefault;
    if (zone == null) {
        synchronized(DateTimeZone.class) {
            zone = cDefault;
            if (zone == null) {
                DateTimeZone temp = null;
                try {
                    try {
                        temp = forID(System.getProperty("user.timezone"));
                    } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
                        // ignored
                    }
                    if (temp == null) {
                        temp = forTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
                    }
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
                    // ignored
                }
                if (temp == null) {
                    temp = UTC;
                }
                cDefault = zone = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    return zone;
}
```

forID(String) calls getDefault(), which creates the loop:

```
 public static DateTimeZone forID(String id) {
    if (id == null) {
        return getDefault();
    }
    if (id.equals("UTC")) {
        return DateTimeZone.UTC;
    }
    DateTimeZone zone = cProvider.getZone(id);
    if (zone != null) {
        return zone;
    }
    if (id.startsWith("+") || id.startsWith("-")) {
        int offset = parseOffset(id);
        if (offset == 0L) {
            return DateTimeZone.UTC;
        } else {
            id = printOffset(offset);
            return fixedOffsetZone(id, offset);
        }
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("The datetime zone id is not recognised: " + id);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the looping part is only in the joda code, I would say that's a bug.

---

It has been corrected on the [trunk](http://joda-time.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/joda-time/trunk/JodaTime/src/main/java/org/joda/time/DateTimeZone.java?revision=1569&view=markup#l137) and will be available in V2.0.

---

**Resources :**

- [The reported bug](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3056104&group_id=97367&atid=617889)

Comment: Gave you the answer for link to trunk and bug report - I couldn't find either!

Answer (score 3):

Looks like it's a bug in that it assumes the `user.timezone` property will have been set.

That's the way to get round it in this case - just make sure that user.timezone is set appropriately. It's a shame that you have to though.

Joda Time uses "null means default" in a lot of places - unfortunately, in my view. I prefer "null is invalid" usually. In [Noda Time](http://noda-time.googlecode.com) (a port of Joda Time to .NET) we're trying to get rid of a lot of this kind of thing - as well as preventing the default time zone from being as prevalent in the first place.